# Xpath - how to seclect "Text2"

Tags: xpath

```
<td>
  <script type="text/javascript" style=""><!--document.write("Text1");//--></script>
  Text2
  <noscript><em>Text3</em></noscript>
</td>
```

I'm looking to get the output: Text2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text2` is a child of `<td>`, and it's a text node.  Technically there are two other text nodes under `<td>`, but they contain only whitespace and so are ignored by most XPath processors.

So you can select the text node containing `Text2` with

```
(/td/text())[1]
```

Comment: The statement "they are ignored by XPath" is too broad. More accurately, some XPath processors choose to present a view of the document in which whitespace text nodes have been eliminated. There's nothing in the XPath spec that legitimises such behaviour. The quote from the XPath spec says you can't have zero-length text nodes, but it doesn't say you can't have whitespace-only text nodes.